# maven -version выдает ошибку при запуске с терминала, хоть и среда настроена верно

Tags: java, maven

ошибка следующая:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:140)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

Все переменные среды я как только не настраивал не помогает, мне нужен мавен из терминала. Хоть он и работает в IDE

[image: настройка среды 2]
[image: настройка среды 1]

Answer (score 0):

в итоге прописал в PATH путь до maven из ide и он начал запускаться через терминал